# Microsoft Graph API: Omit user access token

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'd like to run some periodic checks from a web server (checking for new files in a OneDrive directory), this means there is no logged in user, is it possible to access Graph endpoints with just the permissions that the application has?

I.e. using the Application Id and Password/Public Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In endpoint documentation you can find which permission is required as in the example below:

[image]

Make sure you obtain access token [without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) to have it working.

You can also check your token using jwt.io and make sure it's payload contains appropriate role.

Comment: I ended working through a variation of that article from multiple sources, I started writing up an answer but you posted this which is correct and matches close enough what I ended up doing.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa feel free to add something to my answer or let me know what I can add more so the answer is more complete :)

Comment: The main variance I had was getting the bearer token, I used what I think is the older URL of https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token and provided "https://graph.microsoft.com" as the resource.

Comment: Not sure if I see what would be valuable to add, so feel free to add it yourself.